# Solr Join two data sources in the same core

Tags: solr, datasource

I have two datasources in the same solr core.
datasource 1: candidates (this is JDBC datasource)
datesource 2: pdf (this is file system datasource [all of them are pdf])
there is a mapping between the two datasources using the pdf file name
in candidates, the field name is **PDFName** and in pdf, its name is **fileName**
Now:
I want to get all candidates who have in their pdf files the word **radiology**

```
http://solr.example.com:8888/solr/mycore/select?q=*:*&facet=true&fq={!join%20from=fileName%20to=PDFName}pdfbody:radiology&rows=10
```

is giving 

`<result name="response" numFound="33681" start="0">`

33681 is all of my docs!!
while i was expecting to get 26 only as

```
http://solr.example.com:8888/solr/mycore/select?q=*:*&facet=true&fq=pdfbody:radiology&start=0&rows=10

the result is
<result name="response" numFound="26" start="0">
```

any idea what i missed or did wrong?

Comment: what is the solr version you are using?

Comment: @notdang , I am using solr jetty 
solr-spec-version 4.0.0.2011.09.07.12.37.34
Does it make any difference ?!

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with your index. Please add debugQuery=true parameter and show the response